# Calling a control method in an Ajax call and error for converting array to string

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to call my controller method which calls a model method in an Ajax call.

Here is my Ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                                            dataType: "json",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('siteController/fetchEmployees') ?>",
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        html = "<table id='myTable'><thead><tr id='test'><th>ID</th><th>FName</th><th> LName</th></tr></thead><tbody id='contentTable'>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        {
                            html = html + "<tr  id='trResponses' ><td><div >" + data[i]['ID'] + "</div></td><td><div >" + data[i]['FName'] + "</div></td><td><div >" + data[i]['LName'] + "</div></td></tr>";                        
                        }
                         html = html + "</tbody></table>";
                         $("#resultFrm2").html(html);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('error');
                    }                
                });
```

and my siteController has the following method:

```
 public function fetchEmployees() 
 {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    return json_encode($this->user_model->getAll());
}
```

and my Model method is as following:

```
public function getAll() 
{
    $q = $this->db->get('users');        
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

but since my return in controller is an array I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion
```

Do you know how I can handle this issue?

If my question is not clear please let me know which part you need more clarification?

**ADDED:
I did all of your suggestions and mentioned all of my changes in here too! but now there is no out put for Ajax however if in my controller instead of return json_encode($this->user_model->getAll()); I use var_dump( json_encode($this->user_model->getAll())); I can see data in response!**
Thanks

Comment: You need to `echo` the response, don't use return: `echo json_encode(...)`

Comment: YEa please put it in a new message so I can accept it as an answer please

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood why we are using json_encode: since my out put is an array we need to use json_encode and in the ajax call when the datatype is "Json" it decodes to an array! however if my out put was just a single element like count() a single number in that case I wouldnt need to use datatype: "json" and json_encode, right?Also is it a good practice to use echo in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

You need to return a json array

In your ajax call set

```
dataType: "json"
```

and in your fetchEmployees() function

```
echo json_encode($this->user_model->getAll());
```

This will transmit the php array as a string which will the be turned into a javascript array when received by your ajax function.

Comment: Could you please guide morE? in Model or controller? and then in view it should be decoded?

Comment: In your ajax call set dataType: "json" and in your fetchEmployees() function "return json_encode($this->user_model->getAll());". This will transmit the php array as a string which will the be turned into a javascript array when received by your ajax function.

Comment: Thanks so much man! I did but now ajax does not return anything anymore!:( however if before returning in my controller (        return json_encode($this->user_model->getAll());) if I mention =>var_dump( json_encode($this->user_model->getAll())); in my ajax response in Firebug I can see data!

Comment: You need to `echo` from the controller, not `return`. Data must be outputted, that's why `var_dump` works (it sends an output)

Comment: man you are awesome put in a new message I need to accept it as an answer! Please

Comment: Edited my answer. You do need to echo the data, not just return it.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood why we are using json_encode: since my out put is an array we need to use json_encode and in the ajax call when the datatype is "Json" it decodes to an array! however if my out put was just a single element like count() a single number in that case I wouldnt need to use datatype: "json" and json_encode, right?

Comment: You don't have much choice as its a response is to an Ajax call. If you wanted to, you could return the content of of a view that eched the json string but its a bit overkill for the sake of.sticking to a MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an issue with your siteController - echo accepts and returns a string, and you're passing it an array. You want to change `echo($this->user_model->getAll());` to `return json_encode($this->user_model->getAll());`

An AJAX response is in the form of JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), you'll get a JavaScript ParseError if you don't `json_encode` first.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Gavin's got it right, above. You've got to `json_encode` your data. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Now I encoded when I want to return in my controller method, but now my Ajax does not return anything anymore! Do I need to decode it in View? Could you please let me know how?